# Maven 3.3.3 manual installation Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: maven, maven-3, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install Maven 3.3.3 manually. I have downloaded `maven-3.3.3.tar.gz` file from Apache Maven website and extracted it in `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3`. I have tried setting up my `PATH` using `MAVEN_HOME` and `M2_HOME` system property but I am not able to install Maven.

I have tried `sudo apt-get install`, `apt-get cache` also.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you have extracted it but can not install means since that is pretty much all there is to it.

Here is what I do:

```
shackle@shackle-desktop:~$ cd /usr/local/
shackle@shackle-desktop:/usr/local$ sudo tar -xzf ~/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz 
shackle@shackle-desktop:/usr/local$ export PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/:$PATH
shackle@shackle-desktop:/usr/local$ export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3/
shackle@shackle-desktop:/usr/local$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T07:57:37-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_66, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_66/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-32-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Comment: thanks dude , i downloaded the src.tar.gz instead of -bin.tar.gz so there was the glitch .... thanks for explaining it so well ..@WillShackleford

Comment: i am installing now the mahout using but i get these error when i run mvn install , kindly help .....Reactor Summary:
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.1:process (default) on project mahout-buildtools: Error finding remote resources manifests: /usr/local/mahout/trunk/buildtools/target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]